# Change permissions of a folder in Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I created a shared folder in Ubuntu which is located in Virtualbox.

When I open that folder I am getting this error line:

```
You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of "sf_ubuntu"
```

Comment: i think this link may help you [File permission issues with shared folders under Virtual Box ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52667/file-permission-issues-with-shared-folders-under-virtual-box-ubuntu-guest-wind "File permission issues with shared folders under Virtual Box")